# Server.MapPath not working in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need to fetch whether the image exist or not in folder path.
I am using the below code:

```
bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(FolderPath + "Logo.png"));
```

But the bool variable returns false if the file exists.

Comment: What is `FolderPath`?

Comment: Try Path.Combine(folderPath , "Logo.png")

Comment: FolderPath is a string,which is the physical path of image.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you should use `File.Exists` instead.

```
bool isExists = System.IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath(FolderPath + "Logo.png"));
```